# Finding Smooth Numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

This is a German Olympiad exercise from 2015.

> Call a number $n\in\mathbb{N}$ *smooth* if there are $a_1,...,a_n\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that
> $$
> a_1+a_2+...+a_n=a_1\cdot a_2\cdot ... \cdot a_n=n.
> $$
> Find all smooth numbers.

---

So I think that it is evident that every composite number can be written as
$$
n=a_1+...+a_m=a_1\cdot ...\cdot a_m
$$
for $m\leq n$. Because we just take one prime factor of and then add only $1$s.

But the number is smooth if $m=n$. I have trouble finding solutions, I found the obvious solution $1=1$. Has anyone got an idea of how to find more or all smooth numbers?

Comment: Which Olympiad?

Comment: @Shaun German olympiad

Comment: If this is an ongoing competition, pleas do not answer.

Comment: @trula Its from 2015.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, let's assume $n$ is an odd smooth number. Let $m_1$ be the number of $a_i$'s which are $\equiv 1\pmod{4}$ and $m_2$ be the number of $a_i$'s which are $\equiv -1\pmod{4}$. Then, we will have:
$$m_1+m_2=n  \ (*),\\ m_1-m_2 \equiv n\pmod{4} \ \ (**), \\ (-1)^{m_2} \equiv n\pmod{4}  \ \ \ (***).$$

From $(*)$ and $(**)$, we conclude that $2m_2 \equiv 0 \pmod{4}$. Hence $m_2$ must be even. Now, by $(***)$, it is clear that we must have $n=4k+1$ for some $k \in \mathbb N.$ In this case,
$$4k+1=\underbrace{1+1+\cdots+1}_{2k}+\underbrace{(-1)+(-1)+\cdots+(-1)}_{2k}+(4k+1).$$

---

Now, let's assume $n$ is an even smooth number. If $n$ is of the form $4k+2$ for some $k \in \mathbb N,$ then exactly one of the $a_i$'s, say $a_n$, must be even. Therefore, $a_1+ ... + a_{4k+1}=n-a_n=(4k+2)-a_n$, which is impossible because the left hand of the identity is odd while the right hand is even. Hence, an even smooth number must be a multiple of $4$.

---

If $n=8k$ where $k \in \mathbb N$, then:

$$8k=\underbrace{1+1+\cdots+1}_{4k-2}+\underbrace{(-1)+(-1)+\cdots+(-1)}_{2k}+\underbrace{1+1+\cdots+1}_{2k}+2+(4k).$$

---

If $n=16k+4$ where $k \in \mathbb N$, then:

$$16k+4=-2 + 2 + (4k+1) +\underbrace{1+1+\cdots+1}_{12k+3}+\underbrace{(-1)+(-1)+\cdots+(-1)}_{2k-2} \\ +\underbrace{1+1+\cdots+1}_{2k-2}+(-1)+(1).$$

---

If $n=16k+12$ where $k \in \mathbb N$, then:

$$16k+12=2 + 2 + (4k+3) +\underbrace{1+1+\cdots+1}_{12k+5}+\underbrace{(-1)+(-1)+\cdots+(-1)}_{2k+2} \\ +\underbrace{1+1+\cdots+1}_{2k+2}.$$

---

We are done.

Answer (score 1):

HINT.-One has
$$4n+1=\underbrace{1+1+\cdots+1}_{2n}+\underbrace{-1-1-\cdots-1}_{2n}+(4n+1)$$
$$4n+1=(1)^{2n}(-1)^{2n}(4n+1)$$
In other words, all integer $N\equiv1\pmod4$ is smooth.

It is maybe a partial answer because it remains to look at $N\equiv2,3,0\pmod4$.

However it is clear that $N=2$ is not smooth because $x+y=xy=2$ has not integer solutions. I invite somebody to examine the probable impossibility of the remian cases. I have no time now.